# ValueError: object has no field when using monkeypatch.setattr on a pydantic.BaseModel's method

Tags: python, pytest, pydantic, monkeypatching

I usually can patch methods of normal objects using pytest monkeypatch. However when I try with a `pydantic.BaseModel` it fails.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int

    def intro(self) -> str:
        return f"I am {self.name}, {self.age} years old."


def test_person_intro(monkeypatch):
    p = Person(name='Joe', age=20)
    monkeypatch.setattr(p, 'intro', lambda: 'patched intro')
    assert p.intro() == 'patched intro'
```

Raises:

```py
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x10f0d3040>

    def test_intro(monkeypatch):
        p = Person(name='Joe', age=20)
>       monkeypatch.setattr(p, 'intro', lambda: 'patched intro')

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
>   ???
E   ValueError: "Person" object has no field "intro"

pydantic/main.py:422: ValueError
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could patch the type:

```
def test_person_intro(monkeypatch):
    p = Person(name='Joe', age=20)
    monkeypatch.setattr(Person, 'intro', lambda self: 'patched intro')
    assert p.intro() == 'patched intro'
```

Or you could set item in the instance dict:

```
def test_person_intro(monkeypatch):
    p = Person(name='Joe', age=20)
    monkeypatch.setitem(p.__dict__, 'intro', lambda: 'patched intro')
    assert p.intro() == 'patched intro'
```

The reason an instance setattr isn't working as usual is that [`pydantic.BaseModel` overrides `__setattr__`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.6/pydantic/main.py#L357) to only allow a restricted set of names. You will see the same error doing `person.intro = "other"` as well, it is unrelated to pytest's monkeypatch fixture.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify from the answer by wim, If wanting to patch manually, this worked for me:

```
p.__dict__['myattr'] = 'myval'
```

After this, `p.myattr` also worked.